# How to filter out a "NULL" valued line if there's another line that is otherwise identical but doesn't have a "NULL" value?

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause, sql-null

As you can see from the image. Lines 5 and 6 are otherwise identical but line 5 has "NULL" value. So I want to filter line 5 out but leave line 6.

Then there are also single lines that have "NULL" value but I also want to keep those. So how can I do this? How can I keep the single/unique lines that have "NULL" value and simultaneously filter out lines that have an identical counterpart but the counterpart has a "NULL" value?

I've tried to use coalesce group by -function but haven't got the wanted results yet.

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I started to write an answer, but quit when I couldn't copy the column names...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    date_updated is not null
    or not exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.state = t.state
            and t1.foo = t.foo
            and t1.date_created = t.date_created
            and t1 date_created is not null
    )
```

Another option is window functions, if your database supports them:

```
select *
from (
    select  
        t.*,
        max(date_updated) over(partition by state, foo, date_created) max_date_updated
    from mytable t
) t
where date_updated is not null or max_date_updated is null
```